# yii2 url manager is not parsing second parameter

Tags: php, routes, yii2

I try to setup some rest controller for products managing. I want action to ne run from url: /product/decrease/4/8
in url manager i have:

```
'rules' => array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>/<id2:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        )
```

I have error like this:

```
<response><name>Bad Request</name><message>Missing required parameters: decrease</message><code>0</code><status>400</status><type>yii\web\BadRequestHttpException</type></response>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: **Missing required parameters: decrease** says it all, right?

Comment: I don't get it. I thought decrease is action name not parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Your Rules look ok, however I do not believe this rule

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>/<id2:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
```

Will be triggered, because it is after this rule

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
```

the shorter one will always be triggered first. So I would switch them around. Then test again.

Afterwards take care of the decrease parameter, are you sure you do not have a variable named like that?